# Update date and disable automatic updates

Tags: date, ntp

Ubuntu 20.04 running in VirtualBox with MacOS host

Using `python` rather than a shell script.  For `linux` commands running in a sub-process.  Date is updated,  however not long after date/time is reset back automatically.  Have disabled NTP.  How do I prevent date being reset back to actual date?

```
import re, shutil, csv, subprocess, yaml, click
from pathlib import Path

def cmd(cmd:str="ls -al", assertfail=True) :
    up = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, close_fds=True)
    str = [o.rstrip().decode() for o in up.stdout]
    exitcode = up.wait()
    if assertfail: assert exitcode == 0, f"[{exitcode}] {cmd} {str}"
    return exitcode,  str

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # set date back before flash EOL date
    import datetime as dt
    n = dt.datetime.now()
    if n.year > 2020:
        systime = dt.datetime(n.year-1, n.month, n.day, n.hour, n.minute, n.second, n.microsecond).isoformat(sep=' ', timespec='milliseconds')
        cmd("sudo timedatectl set-ntp off")
        cmd(f"sudo date --set=\"{systime}\"")
        # cmd("sudo hwclock --systohc")
        cmd(f"sudo timedatectl set-time \"{systime}\"")
        e, out = cmd("sudo timedatectl status")
        print("\n".join(out))
        e, out = cmd("date")
        print(f"updated time {dt.datetime.now()} {out[0]}")
```

### output

```
               Local time: Fri 2020-01-24 21:55:05 UTC
           Universal time: Fri 2020-01-24 21:55:05 UTC
                 RTC time: Fri 2020-01-24 21:55:05
                Time zone: Etc/UTC (UTC, +0000)
System clock synchronized: no
              NTP service: inactive
          RTC in local TZ: no
updated time 2020-01-24 21:55:05.980812 Fri 24 Jan 2020 09:55:05 PM UTC
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you installed the VirtualBox Guest Additions? If so, there is a function in there that will regularly update the VM time to match the host, which can result in the situation you seem to be facing. Fortunately, it's not too difficult to disable.

0. Open Terminal
1. Disable `GetHostTimeDisabled` for the VM(s) you do not want to have sync with the host:

   ```
   % VBoxManage setextradata "{VM Name}" "VBoxInternal/Devices/VMMDev/0/Config/GetHostTimeDisabled" 1
   ```
2. Start the VM

***Note:** Be sure to replace `{VM Name}` with the proper name of your virtual machine.*

This setting is VM-specific and persistent so, even if you update the Guest Additions software for that VM, you will not need to re-disable the `GetHostTimeDisabled` function.

Comment: brilliant thanks - this now means date/time stays to what I set it to

Comment: Can you see any reason I'm seeing issues with 20.10? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1310907/ubuntu-20-10-virtualbox-unattended