# Ubuntu 20.10 VirtualBox unattended

Tags: virtualbox

VirtualBox 6.1.16
Host: MacOS 10.15.7

1. downloaded [Ubuntu 20.10 live-server ISO](https://releases.ubuntu.com/20.10/)
2. checked `sha256sum`
3. created VM using `VBoxManage createvm`
4. install `VBoxManage unattended install`

This fails for Ubuntu 20.10,  works for 20.04.  See details below.  Are there any changes needed for Ubuntu 20.10?

### 20.10 Failure

```
$ VBoxManage unattended install mcs-ui --iso=/Users/rraymond/projects/mediacentre/downloads/ubuntu-20.10-live-server-amd64.iso
```

```
VBoxManage: info: Preparing unattended installation of Ubuntu_64 in machine 'mcs-ui' (5307088b-cdc3-479e-a233-a296abcb9eb1).
VBoxManage: error: ISO reader fail to open '/Users/rraymond/projects/mediacentre/downloads/ubuntu-20.10-live-server-amd64.iso' (VERR_VFS_UNSUPPORTED_FORMAT): Volume space size for joliet volume descriptor differs from primary: 0x7c0e1 vs 0x7cb3f

VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component UnattendedWrap, interface IUnattended, callee nsISupports
VBoxManage: error: Context: "ConstructMedia()" at line 1859 of file VBoxManageMisc.cpp
```

### 20.04 Success

```
$ VBoxManage unattended install mcs-ui --iso=/Users/rraymond/projects/mediacentre/downloads/ubuntu-20.04-live-server-amd64.iso
```

```
VBoxManage: info: Preparing unattended installation of Ubuntu_64 in machine 'mcs-ui' (5307088b-cdc3-479e-a233-a296abcb9eb1).
VBoxManage: info: Using values:
                           isoPath = /Users/rraymond/projects/mediacentre/downloads/ubuntu-20.04-live-server-amd64.iso
                              user = vboxuser
                          password = changeme
                      fullUserName = 
                        productKey = 
                  additionsIsoPath = /Applications/VirtualBox.app/Contents/MacOS/VBoxGuestAdditions.iso
             installGuestAdditions = false
              validationKitIsoPath = 
            installTestExecService = false
                            locale = en_US
                           country = US
                          timeZone = Europe/London
                             proxy = 
                          hostname = mcs-ui.myguest.virtualbox.org
       packageSelectionAdjustments = 
                 auxiliaryBasePath = /Users/rraymond/VirtualBox VMs/mcs-ui/Unattended-5307088b-cdc3-479e-a233-a296abcb9eb1-
                        imageIndex = 1
                scriptTemplatePath = /Applications/VirtualBox.app/Contents/MacOS/UnattendedTemplates/ubuntu_preseed.cfg
     postInstallScriptTemplatePath = /Applications/VirtualBox.app/Contents/MacOS/UnattendedTemplates/debian_postinstall.sh
                postInstallCommand = 
      extraInstallKernelParameters =  auto=true preseed/file=/cdrom/preseed.cfg priority=critical quiet splash noprompt noshell automatic-ubiquity debian-installer/locale=en_US keyboard-configuration/layoutcode=us languagechooser/language-name=English localechooser/supported-locales=en_US.UTF-8 countrychooser/shortlist=US --
                          language = en-US
                  detectedOSTypeId = Ubuntu_64
                 detectedOSVersion = 20.04 LTS "Focal Fossa" - Release amd64
                  detectedOSFlavor = 
               detectedOSLanguages = en-US
                   detectedOSHints = 
VBoxManage: info: VM 'mcs-ui' (5307088b-cdc3-479e-a233-a296abcb9eb1) is ready to be started (e.g. VBoxManage startvm).
```

Comment: Please check if somebody has already filed a bug report for the 20.10 failure. If not, please file it.